# linq-to-sql combine child expressions

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda

I need to create and combine several expressions for child entity into one to use it on "Any" operator of a parent. Code now looks like this:

```
Expresion<Child, bool> startDateExpression;

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate)
     startDateExpression = t => true;
else
     startDateExpression = t => t.start_date >= startDate;

Expression<Child, bool> endDateExpression;

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)
     endDateExpression = t => true;
else
     endDateExpression = t => t => t.end_date <= endDate;


....
ParameterExpression param = startDateExpression.Parameters[0];

Expression<Func<T, bool>> Combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<Child, bool>>( 
        Expression.AndAlso(startDateExpression.Body, endDateExpression.Body), param);

//but now I am trying to use combined expression on parent 
//this line fails just to give an idea on what I am trying to do:
//filter type is IQueryable<Parent>;
var filter = filter.Where(p =>p.Children.Any(Combined));
```

How can I do that? Is there better(more elegant way way of doing it? Maybe I should convert child expression into parent expression?

Comment: compile error - delegate does not take 1 argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you are building expressions instead of using lambda functions. Have you tried the following?

```
var filter = filter.Where(p =>p.Children.Any(
   child => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate) || child.start_date >= startDate) &&
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate) || child.end_date <= endDate)
));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Because it's a dynamically created search criteria I have to do use expressions, see my update

Comment: @VictorS: I still don't see why you need to build the Expressions yourself. See if my updated answers solves your needs.

Comment: This will probably fail since both child.start_date and child.end_date are DateTime? but I can use DateTime.MinimumValue instead

Comment: This gives me following compile error: "Delegate<System.Func<Parent, int, bool> does not take '1' arguments

Comment: Never give up:-) in fact I made it work like this: var filter = filter.Where(p =>p.Children.Any( child => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate) || child.start_date >= DateTime.Parse(startDate)) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate) || child.end_date <= DateTime.Parse(endDate) )); Now I will just append some more conditions I left off for clarity

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much, using expressions would be more elegant but never used them in "Any" operator.